# How can I achieve a flattened array of promises from a forEach loop?

Tags: javascript, promise, q

I am attempting to utilize a chain of promises (via Q & the node child-process-promise library) to pull drive letters, free space, and total size utilizing the Windows WMIC command like so:

```
var stdout = '';
var exec = require('child-process-promise').exec;

exec('wmic logicaldisk where drivetype=3 get caption', { capture: ['stdout', 'stderr'] })
    .then(function(result) {
        var data = result.stdout.split('\r\n');
        data = data.splice(1, data.length - 3);
        data = data.map(Function.prototype.call, String.prototype.trim);
        data.forEach(function(drive) {
            // This is where I am getting hung up
        });
    })
    .then(function(result) {
        console.log(result);
    })
    .fail(function(err) {
        console.error(err);
    });
```

As you can in the code above, I am returning an array of drive letters from the initial execution of WMIC, though after this I will need to run WMIC several more times depending on the count of drives returned by the first query.  For instance, if my data array looks like so:

```
['C:','D:']
```

I'll need to run:

```
wmic logicaldisk where caption="C:" get freespace
wmic logicaldisk where caption="C:" get size
wmic logicaldisk where caption="D:" get freespace
wmic logicaldisk where caption="D:" get freespace
```

Though I would like to do this from a flat promise chain to aggregate the results, I cannot seem to wrap my head around how to do this.  I've seen several other questions where utilizing a "reduce" is suggested, but can't seem to figure how to apply this to my current situation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a collection of Promises by iterating over the data and storing the result of each call to `exec` in an array. Then wait for the resolution of all the Promises by passing the array to `Q#all`.

**Using nested `forEach`**:

```
var promises = [];

data.forEach(function (drive) {
    var commands = [
        'wmic logicaldisk where caption="' + drive + '" get freespace',
        'wmic logicaldisk where caption="' + drive + '" get size'
    ];

    commands.forEach(function (cmd) {
        promises.push(exec(cmd, {capture: ['stdout', 'stderr']}));
    });
});

return Q.all(promises);
```

**Or using `reduce` and `map`**:

```
var promises = data.reduce(function (result, drive) {
    var commands = [
        'wmic logicaldisk where caption="' + drive + '" get freespace',
        'wmic logicaldisk where caption="' + drive + '" get size'
    ].forEach(function (cmd) {
        result.push(exec(cmd, {capture: ['stdout', 'stderr']}));
    });

    return result;
}, []);

return Q.all(promises);
```

Comment: After tinkering around I was getting very close to a similar solution!  Will this always return the executed commands in the same order?  It appears this is the case as per the Q documentation..

Comment: Yes, as we are dealing with arrays the order will be maintained.

Comment: Excellent, I appreciate the prompt response and clarification!